# How to do the regression by tensorflow in this example?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I am using tensorflow to do a linear regression. Here I am facing a problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8,6)

data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
xs = data["A"][:100]
ys = data["B"][:100]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]),name = 'weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]),name = 'bias')

Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X,W), b)

sample_num = xs.shape[0]
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(Y_pred - Y,2))/sample_num
learning_rate = 0.0001
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

n_samples = xs.shape[0]
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(100):
        for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
            _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: x, Y:y})

    W, b = sess.run([W, b])

plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo', label='Real data')
plt.plot(xs, xs*W + b, 'r', label='Predicted data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The data.csv is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YZOwM1iXXuC4rIBbzCA0ubn_Zt5pxNMq).

The plot is diametrically opposed to what I expected:
[image]
So, what is the problem? I am a beginner of python and tensorflow, and just can't reach the points.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the learning rate ? 0.0001 is rather small. And what kind of loss values do you get ?

Comment: @Sunreef I tried to increasing the learning rate, but the variables 'W', 'b' and also the 'loss' will turn to be 'None'. The predicted data will not be plotted. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: @Sunreef My tensorflow is installed by pip, it always shows many warnings. Can these effect the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nipun mentioned, try `AdamOptimizer` instead of `GradientDescentOptimizer`.

You will often find that `AdamOptimizer` is generally a better optimizer than `GradientDescentOptimizer` and reaches the minima much faster.

It does so by adapting the learning rate instead of keeping it constant (`0.0001` in your case).

Also, more the number of epochs, better the model (not considering over-fitting here).

Answer (score 1):

Since your learning rate and the number of epochs are too small, your regression models haven't converged. Therefore, you may need to increase the **learning rate** and use the **tf.train.AdamOptimizer**.

Here I set the learning rate to 2, epochs=10000 and got the following graph.

[image]

Here I have given the code with the comments where necessary.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (8, 6)

data = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
xs = data["A"][:100]
ys = data["B"][:100]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='X')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='Y')

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='weight')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='bias')

Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(Y_pred - Y, 2))
learning_rate = 2 #increase the learning rate
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)#use the AdamOptimizer

BATCH_SIZE = 8 #Batch Size define here

n_samples = xs.shape[0]
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(10000): #increase the num of epoches
        for start, end in zip(range(0, n_samples, BATCH_SIZE), # mini batch Gradientdecent
                              range(BATCH_SIZE, n_samples + 1, BATCH_SIZE)):
            _, l = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={X: xs[start:end], Y: ys[start:end]})

    prediction = sess.run(Y_pred, feed_dict={X: xs})
    #W, b = sess.run([W, b])

plt.plot(xs, ys, 'bo', label='Real data')
plt.plot(xs, prediction, 'r', label='Predicted data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Also, you can use the **mini batch gradientdescent method** to accelerate the convergence as the code above.

Moreover, you can increase the number of epochs and learning rate further to get the optimal result.

Hope this helps.